# SQL Login failure, 18456, STATE 43

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, logins

I've seen Aaron Bertrand's extensive post, and I've asked on Twitter #sqlhelp, but have not gotten an answer for what this error with **state 43** means:

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 43
Login failed for user 'Domain\svcacct'. 
Reason: Failed to send an environment change notification to a 
log shipping partner node. [CLIENT: #.#.#.#]
```

This is a SQL 2016 Standard set up, with 18 Basic Availability Groups.

This Login is valid, except for about 30 minutes last Tuesday when all sorts of *weirdness* happened.  I wish I could define weirdness better, but I am brand new to the environment and still leaning names :)

Comment: So did this happen just during that 30 minute window or is it happening now? Have you checked with any sysadmins concerning the account and AD system?

Comment: Just during that one window...there *might* have been a domain controller communication issue that is being investigated.   Mostly curious if anyone has seen this State 43 or any MS docs on it...I've used up my Google-Fu on this

Comment: Without more information, hard to say but I could speculate at what happened. The client connection was interrupted *but* recoverable, however something in the session had changed such as the database context. When the session was attempted to be recovered the error occurred due to the environment session change which didn't match what was stored. That's my best guess given just the error. (note the error says log shipping partner but it's an old error message and also applies to log shipping, availability groups, and mirroring).

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft thanks...no internal super secret documentation on State 43?   Or public that I just didn't find?   Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Nothing public that I could see, can't comment on internal. I looked in the source to see where the error crops up. If you are getting this a bunch, take a trace/XE and look for the connection getting the error, see if it's changing databases, collation, language, etc., and then getting disconnected.